# How to convert HTML to RichTextBox in Windows Phone Mango

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is there an easy way to convert HTML to display in the new Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) RichTextBox control.  I'm mostly concerned about retaining links and images without using a web browser control.

thanks,
Sam

Comment: By the way, this class exists in Android SDK. There remains one thing: to wait until someone converts it from java to C#.

Comment: @vorrtex got a link to the java code for this then?

Comment: @Matt Lacey Here is it: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/text/Html.java#HtmlToSpannedConverter

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I need this functionality and am considering writing my own parser - but that sounds pretty awful

Comment: The dates match up too well -- looks like this is yours http://htmltorichtextbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/72960 . If it is, thanks! works great.

Answer (score 1):

I would use HTML Agility pack to parse the HTML and transform each type of node in the equivalent in the Document namespace: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

You need to handle the nested elements and depending of the level of conformity of the HTML, handling bad formatted content can be hard but HA is a good library.

There's a sample in the source code I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public void ConvertRtfToHtml()
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser = 
                                           new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    webBrowser.CreateControl(); // only if needed
    webBrowser.DocumentText = richTextBox1.Text;
    while (webBrowser.DocumentText != richTextBox1.Text)
      Application.DoEvents();
    webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
    webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
    richTextBox2.Paste();
  }
```